# wordpress get excerpt by id

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the [options framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/)

and i can't work out why this doesnt work

```
$x = of_get_option('post_number');
$content_post = get_post($x);
echo $content_post->post_excerpt;
```

its very odd because

```
echo of_get_option('post_number');
```

works perfectly and outputs a number

and according to [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) my code should work
yet the echo produces nothing, not even an error message

so i must be handeling get_post() incorrectly somehow, any clues?

---

EDIT

var dump http://pastebin.com/ZEgQ5WPn
reveals that post_content is full but post_excerpt is empty

how do i regenerate the excerpt?

---

EDIT [resolved]

i decided to manualy overwrite the excerpt but my option was missing, then i found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/just-upgraded-to-31-and-post-excerpt-field-in-admin-disappeared#post-2342181)

and used

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

to manualy write the excerpt

Comment: have you tried printing the object? ie: echo "<pre>"; print_r($content_post); echo "</pre>"; then see what thats outputting, chances are, post excerpt is empty?

Comment: @Marty it outputs this - http://pastebin.com/ZEgQ5WPn

Answer (score 30):

```
$text = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));
```

Comment: Seriously, this is awesome. Had no idea it existed.

Comment: top quality an answer from 2014 still rules

Answer (score 3):

This will take the post_content and create an excerpt out of it. You can substitute the post_content for any other string of code. Change the 55 to another number to increase the amount of words returned.

```
$excerpt = wp_trim_words ( strip_shortcodes( $recent["post_content"], 55 ) );
```

Comment: this thread is 3 years old, i resolved the issue ages ago as indicated in the edits, ill make a self answer to close this

Comment: You just like, saved mah loife. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) like this, which [returns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return) almost all built-in post attributes as part of the post object.

```
<?php
  $my_id = 7;
  $my_post = get_post( $my_id ); 
  $my_excerpt = $my_post->post_excerpt;
  var_dump( $my_excerpt );
?>
```

If that fails (it shouldn't, but perhaps you've tried by the sound of it) maybe checkout out [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and pass in `"p=$my_id"` as a param. This is likely the function used under the get_post hood anyways.

```
<?php
  $my_id = 7;
  $my_posts = new WP_Query( "p=$my_id" ); 
  var_dump( $my_posts );
?>
```

Comment: first code block returned : string(0) "" - second block did this http://pastebin.com/MDgRq2cq

Comment: The blank string (versus null) suggests your excerpt is blank. maybe check out what this query returns (by hand): `SELECT   blueroom_posts.* FROM blueroom_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND blueroom_posts.ID = 9 AND blueroom_posts.post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY blueroom_posts.post_date DESC`

Comment: but according to this other dump, its not empty http://pastebin.com/ZEgQ5WPn this thing is driving me nuts, everything looks like it should work, and there so little code to look through just makes it worse

Comment: or at least it shows the content is full, but excerpt is empty, so wierd